# How can I hide and unhide views in SwiftUI with proper onAppear and onDisappear and keep state?

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to hide and unhide views in SwiftUI, but it seems quite difficult. I am not able to keep a continuation of state when I'm hiding and unhiding my views.

```swift
struct CounterView: View {
    var title: String
    var delay = 0.5
    
    @State var ticker: Int = 0
    @State var visible = IsVisible()
    
    class IsVisible {
        var bool: Bool = false
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(title) \(ticker)")
            .onAppear {
                print("\(title) onAppear")
                if !self.visible.bool {
                    self.visible.bool = true
                    startCounter()
                }
            }
            .onDisappear {
                print("\(title) onDisappear")
                self.visible.bool = false
            }
    }
    
    func startCounter() {
        self.ticker += 1
        print(self.ticker)
        
        if self.visible.bool {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
                self.startCounter()
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @State var hide = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Button {
                    self.hide.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text(hide ? "Show" : "Hide")
                }
                myView()
            }
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func myView() -> some View {
        let view = CounterView(title: "Test", delay: 0.1)
        if hide {
            view.hidden()
        } else {
            view
        }
    }
}
```

**Steps to reproduce**

```
1. Open app
2. Tap hide
3. Tap show
```

**Expected result**

```
Counter continues from last number When the view is hidden it gets no accidental onAppear callbacks
```

**Actual result**

```
Counter restarts from 0
When hiding the view a new view is created and it gets an onAppear callback
```

**Wanted solution**

Ideally I would either just do

```swift
let view = CounterView(title: "Test", delay: 0.1)
if hide {
    view.hidden()
} else {
    view
}
```

or even better

```swift
CounterView(title: "Test", delay: 0.1).hide(true)
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to work around this issue we need to maintain the state somehow and be able to do something like view.hide(true) without creating a different view tree. By wrapping the view in a UIKit view we can achieve that:

```
Original view structure:
- MyView

New view structure:
- HideableView (SwiftUI)
  -> HideableView.Container (UIView)
     -> UIHostingController (UIView)
        -> MyView (SwiftUI)
```

We then get full control over the lifecycle of the view as we can add and remove the UIHostingController from its superview (HideableView.Container) in this way.

```swift
extension View {
    func hide(_ hide: Bool) -> some View {
        HideableView(isHidden: .constant(hide), view: self)
    }
    
    func hide(_ isHidden: Binding<Bool>) -> some View {
        HideableView(isHidden: isHidden, view: self)
    }
}

struct HideableView<Content: View>: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var isHidden: Bool
    var view: Content
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ViewContainer<Content> {
        return ViewContainer(isContentHidden: isHidden, child: view)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ container: ViewContainer<Content>, context: Context) {
        container.child.rootView = view
        container.isContentHidden = isHidden
    }
    
    class ViewContainer<Content: View>: UIView {
        var child: UIHostingController<Content>
        var didShow = false
        var isContentHidden: Bool {
            didSet {
                addOrRemove()
            }
        }
        
        init(isContentHidden: Bool, child: Content) {
            self.child = UIHostingController(rootView: child)
            self.isContentHidden = isContentHidden
            super.init(frame: .zero)
            addOrRemove()
        }
        
        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
        
        override func layoutSubviews() {
            super.layoutSubviews()
            child.view.frame = bounds
        }
        
        func addOrRemove() {
            if isContentHidden && child.view.superview != nil {
                child.view.removeFromSuperview()
            }
            if !isContentHidden && child.view.superview == nil {
                if !didShow {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if !self.isContentHidden {
                            self.addSubview(self.child.view)
                            self.didShow = true
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    addSubview(child.view)
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

then we can simply do:

```swift
CounterView(title: "Test", delay: 0.1).hide(true)
```

or more explicit if you like:

```swift
HideableView(isHidden: .constant(true), view: CounterView(title: "Test", delay: 0.1))
```

Comment: I wrote a longer piece on this if you like to read here https://hfossli.medium.com/hiding-and-unhiding-views-in-swiftui-9474a839e5c9

Comment: Nice. How to ignore safe area? I test and ignoresSafeArea not working.